# ¿Cómo regresar datos consultados con prepare() de mi DB a mi web?

Tags: php

Primero quiero comentar que me parece 'entendible' usar `prepare()` cuando terceras personas van a **insertar** datos en tu página pero, cuando tú mismo vas a regresar los datos de una base a tu web usando una consulta `SELECT`, entonces no entiendo por que no usar simplemente `query()`.

Yo sé regresar datos usando **query() + msqli_fetch_assoc**, pero ahora que muchos recomiendan `prepare()` no sé como hacer.

Me arroja error de sintaxis si intento hacerlo como antes.

> Error de sintaxis. Aparentemente no funciona igual con query() que con prepare()

Quisiera que por favor alguien pusiera un ejemplo haciendo uso de:

```
prepare() + fetch_assoc
```

Comment: Que error te muestra?

Comment: Error de sintaxis. Aparentemente no funciona igual con query() que con prepare() por eso quiero un ejemplo. Pero la verdad, repito, no entiendo por que debo usar prepare() para SELECT...¿acaso mis datos corren riesgo asi como cuando voy a permitir la insercion de datos?

Comment: Traza de error completa y ejemplo verificable para saber qué es lo que te falla.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Las consultas preparadas son requeridas cuando:

- Un usuario puede insertar data a tu base de datos
- Un usuario puede seleccionar información de tu base de datos por medio de filtros; es decir manda variables que son usadas dentro de operadores `WHERE`
- Un usuario realiza la modificación a los datos de un registro existente
- Los medios por los cuales puede llegar información *viciada* a tu base de datos no son solo los `inputs` de tipo text, sino prácticamente cualquiera que sea susceptible de recibir información por medio del usuario; es decir:

  - input type radio
  - input type email
  - input type date
    etc.

Ahora si tu no vas a solicitarle al usuario ningún dato que requiere del uso de un formulario; entonces usa `query()`.

Por eso el uso de:

```
$id = $_POST["id"];
$query = $conexion->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = ?");
$query->bind_param("i", $id);
```

Sin embargo si tu consulta no depende de valores dinámicos *variables* que llegarán con data por parte del usuario, entonces no es necesario el uso de `prepare()`, ya que no existen datos a preparar e interpolar.

Ejemplo de consulta sin el uso de `prepare` pues no llegan valores dinámicos por parte de quien usa el sistema.

```
$conexion = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "contrasenia", "database");

$consulta = $conexion->query("SELECT * FROM tabla");

while($fila = $consulta->fetch_assoc()){
    echo $fila["columna1"];
}
```

Con ayuda de `->fetch_assoc()` en un estilo orientado a objetos obtenemos los resultados de la consulta en forma de array asociativo, si por ejemplo estuviera recueprando el `id` de la tabla; mi resultado sería similar a este:

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
```

Ahora si por otro lado vas a hacer un `SELECT` pero filtrando datos por medio de un valor dinámico que manda el usuario, tu consulta debería ser así:

```
$conexion = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "contrasenia", "database");

$id = 1;
$consulta = $conexion->prepare("SELECT * FROM tabla WHERE id = ?");
$consulta->bind_param("i", $id);
$consulta->execute();
$valores = $consulta->get_result();

while($fila = $valores->fetch_assoc()){
    echo $fila["columna1"];
    echo $fila["columna2"];
}
```

Hacemos uso de [get result()](https://www.php.net/manual/es/mysqli-stmt.get-result.php), que como indica la documentación de PHP sirve para:

> Obtiene un conjunto de resultados de una sentencia preparada

Comment: Exacto amigo, eso era lo que mi propio sentido comun me decia, pero como en el mismo manual de php se ve que usan prepare() con un select, asi por ejemplo : prepare( SELECT ? FROM datos )...Entonces por eso dudaba, pero yo mismo me decia "para usar 'prepare' si no hay peligro, no estoy abriendo un puente de acceso a mi db a terceras personas??".. Pero ahora que me lo dice otra persona ya suena mucho mas logico. Gracias.

Comment: Y no seria mejor insertar los datos de un usuario con prepare() pero retornar los mismos con query()?? es decir, ponme un ejemplo donde se necesite seleccionar datos de un usuario con prepare()...solo un ejemplo teorico por favor.

Comment: Pero ese "1" del id ¿que seria? ..O sea en que caso se usaria, no entiendo. Tiene que ver con un buscador? Quiero saber el uso practico (solo teoria). No se si me explico.

Comment: o sea mi idea es , por ejemplo, permitir la insercion de datos por parte de terceras personas a mi base de datos, y obviamente hacer esto usando prepare(), pero, una vez que los datos de estas personas esten almacenados en mi db, retornarlos con query(), ¿entiendes? ¿es correcto hacer esto?

Comment: O sea que si yo quiero retornar datos filtrados a mi web, digamos todos los paises que empiecen con P, o todos los trabajadores que tengan un sueldo mayor a 1000, entonces si debo usar prepare()?... Pues la verdad no entiendo muy bien, disculpa. Es que yo pensaba que solo necesitaba seguridad cuando hay un "puente" de ingreso desde mi web a mi servidor..como te dije, en el caso de que alguien inserte datos via formulario tengo claro que hay un puente que debo asegurar; pero en el caso de que yo ya tenga los datos en mi DB y yo mismo los traiga a mi web ¿como podira afectarme hacer esto?

Comment: se supone que las inyecciones pueden ocurrir cuando permites el uso de  los inputs de forms en tu web, cierto? Bueno, para traer los datos no estoy habilitando ningun input...en cambio, si permito insertar datos  si hay habilitados inputs y por ende hay peligro...a eso me refiero

Comment: Espero la teoría que puse al inicio de mi respuesta en esta edición te resuelva u oriente mejor, en caso contrario te invito a revises mas al respecto en la doc de php para aclarar dudas @user137527

Comment: Creo que ahora si entendi. Si el usuario puede filtrar los registros que van a retornar a la web, entonces uso prepare(). Pero si el usuario no va a manipular los datos que van a retornar entonces uso query(). Y eso es lo que quiero hacer: prepare() solo para permitir al usuario la insercion de datos, pero, una vez que éstos estén almacenados, yo no voy a permitir al usuario filtrarlos para luego retornarlos, sino que yo mismo retornaré esos datos..entonces, incluso si yo mismo hago filtros para retornar datos, no hay problema (no necesito Prepare) siempre que solo yo manipule esos datos.